# Matlab: GUI radio button SelectionChangedFn Callback

Tags: matlab, callback, matlab-gui

I'm trying to figure out how to make a GUI with radio buttons that will enable/disable options based on radio button selections. Here's an example of one way I have tried:

```
fig = uifigure('NumberTitle','off','Name','Option Selection','Position',[750,300,460,520]);
panel1 = uipanel(fig,'Title','Options','Position',[140,80,200,280]);
bg = uibuttongroup(fig,'Position',[140 290 200 51],'SelectionChangedFcn',@bselection);
rb1 = uiradiobutton(bg,'Position',[5 30 100 20],'FontWeight','bold');rb1.Text = 'Option 1';
rb2 = uiradiobutton(bg,'Position',[5 10 100 20],'FontWeight','bold');rb2.Text = 'Option 2';
Opt1_label = uilabel(panel1,'text','Option 1','Position',[5 180 100 20],'FontWeight','bold');
Opt1_field = uieditfield(panel1,'text','Position',[5 160 100 20]);
Opt2_label = uilabel(panel1,'text','Option 2','Position',[5 60 250 20],'FontWeight','bold');
Opt2_field = uitextarea(panel1,'Position',[5 15 190 45]);

function bselection(bg,Opt1_label,Opt1_field,Opt2_label,Opt2_field)
if bg.Buttons(1).Value == 1
    Opt1_label.Enable=1;
    Opt1_field.Enable=1;
    Opt2_label.Enable=0;
    Opt2_field.Enable=0;
elseif bg.Buttons(2).Value == 1
    Opt1_label.Enable=0;
    Opt1_field.Enable=0;
    Opt2_label.Enable=1;
    Opt2_field.Enable=1;
end
end
```

The enable/disable if statement works standalone, but I cannot figure out how to get it to work as a callback. Option 2 is not disabled even though option 1 is selected first by default, and if I select another radio button, either nothing changes or I will get an error saying the Enable handle isn't found.

Any ideas are much appreciated
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have configured your function `bgselection()` to be a callback function for a UI element. Callback functions have two specific rules for the input arguments:

1. The first argument must be the handle of the object that called the function, and the second must be "`eventData`" for the callback event. So in your function, the argument `Opt1_label` is being treated as a `eventData` variable. Since it does not have the information expected in that variable, there is an error. So to follow this rule, change your function definition to:

   function bselection(bg,eventData,Opt1_label,Opt1_field,Opt2_label,Opt2_field)
2. The second rule is that if you want to have more than the required two input arguments, you need to list them in a cell array when the function is assigned to the object. So in your case, define the uibuttongroup like this:

   bg = uibuttongroup(fig,'Position',[140 290 200 51],'SelectionChangedFcn',{@bselection,Opt1_label,Opt1_field,Opt2_label,Opt2_field});

You will have to move the definitions of `Opt1_, Opt2_` etc before the `bg` statement, so that they exist and can be included in the cell array.

You can see the documentation for this [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_guis/write-callbacks-for-apps-created-programmatically.html). There are a couple other options for passing arguments, but these are the most common methods.

Also, the `eventData` has some useful information, such as the label of the button that is selected. Try adding `disp(eventData)` to the function to see what is included there.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am no longer getting an error, but the uifigure is still not updating when selecting a radio button. Is there something else I am missing?

Comment: @p.lunder You are right, I did not test that part, but it is an easy fix. I updated my answer to include that.